# sending sentences in url

Tags: html, url, url-encoding

This is an odd question but hopefully someone has an idea of how to work around it

I'm working with a 3rd party product that sends out txt-based emails on the triggering of certain events. I can customize the text of the emails and I have access to certain dynamic properties that I can embed that will be included when the email is generated. So for example assume that I have a dynamic property called %%full-name%%, when it sends the email it would substitute in 'John Smith' in the body of the email.

Now, I need to also embed a url in the email that uses that dynamic property, something like this:

```
http://mysite.com?fullname=%%full-name%%
```

but what will happen is that the 3rd party product has no idea I am embedding a link so it doesn't know to escape it for the space between John and Smith so I get this:

**http://mysite.com?fullname=John** Smith

where the clickable part of the link shows up as just the bolded part in most mail clients.

So my question is, is there a way to wrap that dynamic property such that it will render the link properly despite the spaces? Since its a 3rd party API I'm working with I have zero control over the actual values being passed into the dynamic properties so my options are limited

Comment: I don't think so. You can let the 3rd party know about it though.

Comment: What is the 3rd party? It might have a way of embedding url-safe versions of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the third party vendor this questions. They may have some way of designating that you want a URL encoded dynamic variable in the email.

Comment: This will convert the spaces (which are not allowed in a URL) into either `+` or `%20` depending on the type of encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you surround the link in quotes ("") or greater/less than (<>), most email clients "like outlook" will know that it represents one link and won't cut it off at the space.

```
"http://mysite.com?fullname=%%full-name%%"
<http://mysite.com?fullname=%%full-name%%>
```

You will run into issues if the variable contains other special characters (like: + % & " >).

- edit *
  Have you tried using HTML

  <a href="http://mysite.com?fullname=%%full-name%%">http://mysite.com?fullname=%%full-name%%</a>

Comment: hmm, i tried both options but no dice (in gmail and yahoo at least), thanks for the idea though

Answer (score 0):

If you control the data that is available, you could always maintain another property that is url-safe:

```
Hi, %%full-name%%, visit this link to set your preferences:

http://mysite.com?fullname=%%full-name-url%%"
```

Comment: again, this is a 3rd party product that is a complete black box to us, we have zero control over what it injects or how, all we can do is define the text of the email and the spots it will insert the variables

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't clear whether you were providing the database of "dynamic properties", or whether it was. If you let us know what 3rd party product it is, someone might have experience with it. Otherwise, you're out of luck -- this'll be a text email, and it'll entirely depend on the client receiving the email how to interpret links.